# Error using Artifactory plugin for Flat property from Jenkins

Tags: groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

Jenkins 2.7.2 Pipeline job is not working for 'Flat property' in downloading schema.

While downloading artifacts from generic Artifactory repository (rb-artifactory), Jenkins pipeline job is throwing this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jgit/util/StringUtils
```

I request for your support to resolve this error.

We have the following download schema:

```
def ar_download_logs = """{
  "files": [
    {
      "pattern": "${ar_url}/out/*",
      "flat": "1",
      "target": "logs/"
    }
  ]
}"""
def buildInfo1 = ar_server.download(ar_download_logs)
```

`"flat": "1"` causes the problem while converting from String to Boolean, which uses StringUtil and causing an `exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`.

How to establish dependencies between some of *StringUtils* package for Artifactory Plugin: 2.5.1 to use string to Boolean conversion?

If you take a look at the following source code where the exception occurs, then it’s a Line 79 of *GenericDownloadExecutor.java* as given by the stack trace.

https://github.com/jenkinsci/artifactory-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfrog/hudson/pipeline/executors/GenericDownloadExecutor.java

```
boolean isFlat = file.getFlat() != null && StringUtils.toBoolean(file.getFlat());
```

I also would like to share a plugin that are used for the project:

- Artifactory Plugin: 2.5.1
- Groovy : 1.29
- Ivy Plugin : 1.26
- Pipeline : 2.2
- Pipeline: Groovy : 2.7
- Pipeline: Job : 2.3

Comment: I am trying to get an account on the JFrog JIRA to file this as a bug. I also attempted to file an Issue on the Github repository but it looks like Issues are not enabled for this project. A painful hack might involve adding the org.eclipse.jgit JAR inside of the git-client plugin classpath, which many Jenkins have installed.

Comment: should read "inside of the git-client plugin to the classpath,"

The permanent fix they might implement is to use [commons-lang.BooleanUtils#toBoolean](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/BooleanUtils.html#toBoolean-java.lang.String-) instead of the org.eclipse.jgit equivalent.

Comment: Not an answer, but I was able to enter [a JIRA](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/HAP-829) for this.

Answer (score 6):

Installing [git plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) solves the issue.
In order for this to take affect Jenkins must be restarted after the installation.

Comment: I can vouch for this workaround. It cleared up the error for me.

Answer (score 5):

A fix for this issue is included as part of the Artifactory Plugin [2.8.0](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin#ArtifactoryPlugin-Changelog):
https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/HAP-829

Answer (score 0):

According with other responses, you have 2 options:

- Update your [Artifactory plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin#ArtifactoryPlugin) to [2.8.0 version](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin#ArtifactoryPlugin-Changelog) or ++ because this [issue](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/HAP-829) is solved in the [2.8.0 version](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin#ArtifactoryPlugin-Changelog).
- Use a workaround, installing [Git plugin for Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin).

In these 2 options you need to update or install plugins so you need to restart your Jenkins installation.Restart Jenkins usually takes some minutes.

I recommend you to update your [Artifactory plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin#ArtifactoryPlugin) for solve this issue and posible future issues.